# How can I access nested archives?

Tags: xml, go, zip, archive

I have client and server.
Client sends archives (zip) as []byte to server.
Now server reads them and print all content files names:

```
r, err := zip.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(data), int64(len(data)))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}



for _, zipFile := range r.File {

    if strings.Contains(zipFile.Name, ".tar") {
            fmt.Println(zipFile.Name)

    }

}
```

The trouble is archive has nested archives (tar) with xml files inside, so these names are the names of archives.
How can I access nested archives content (so i can work with xml files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to keep going and access the tar:

```golang
        if strings.Contains(zipFile.Name, ".tar") {
            fmt.Println(zipFile.Name)
            rz, err := zipFile.Open()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            tr := tar.NewReader(rz)

            for {
                hdr, err := tr.Next()
                if err == io.EOF {
                    break // End of archive
                }
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
                if strings.Contains(hdr.Name, ".xml") { 
                    fmt.Printf("Contents of %s:\n", hdr.Name)
                    /*if _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, tr); err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                    }
                    fmt.Println()
                    */
                } 
            }

        }
```

You can see the [documentation for the tar package](https://pkg.go.dev/archive/tar#example-package-Minimal). I used the example and put a comment for file access since I don't know what you want to do with the file.